# How to add two values ​from related tables in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I apologize for the question, but I'm still not good at ASP.NET MVC 5, I ask for help, the task is as follows:

There is a database with two related tables, `RequestProcessing` and `RequestType`. The value of the `DeadLine` column of the `RequestProcessing` table should change depending on the `TimeComplete` value of the `RequestType` table, namely, it consists of the values

```
​​RequestProcessing.DeadLine = RequestProcessing.Date + RequestType.TimeComplete
```

I apologize for such rude formulations. Below I give the classes themselves and the controller method in which I want to get this

```
public class RequestProcessing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Дата поступления")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Комментарий")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Выполнить до")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime DeadLine { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ИД заявки")]
    [Required]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public Request Request { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ФИО")]
    public int? SpecialistId { get; set; }
    public Specialist Specialist { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Статус заявки")]
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Тип заявки")]
    public int? TypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey ("TypeId")]
    public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
}

public class RequestType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Тип заявки")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Данное поле должно содержать не более 50 символов")]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Время на выполнение")]
    [Required]
    public double TimeComplete { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Описание")]
    [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "Данное поле должно содержать не более 300 символов")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]

    public virtual ICollection<RequestProcessing> RequestProcessings { get; set; }
    public RequestType()
    {
        RequestProcessings = new List<RequestProcessing>();
    }
}

public class RequestProcessingController : Controller
{ 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditRequestProcessing(RequestProcessing rProcessing)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RequestProcessing newRProcessing = dbRP.RequestProcessings.Find(rProcessing.Id);

            newRProcessing.Comment = rProcessing.Comment;
            newRProcessing.SpecialistId = rProcessing.SpecialistId;
            newRProcessing.StatusId = rProcessing.StatusId;
            newRProcessing.TypeId = rProcessing.TypeId;

            newRProcessing.DeadLine = rProcessing.Date.AddMinutes(rProcessing.RequestType.TimeComplete);

            dbRP.Entry(newRProcessing).State = EntityState.Modified;
            dbRP.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("RequestProcessing");
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `include`, and fill, and then iterate in your view

Your Action

```
public ActionResult EditRequestProcessing(RequestProcessing rProcessing)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ... do your stuff blah blah

        // get related data
        var relatedProcessingData = db.RequestProcessing.Include(p=>p.RequestType);

        //...
    }

    ...
}
```

In your view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.relatedProcessingData.RequestType)
```

---

**Edit/Update:** I saw you wanted the dead line, just compute calculate that in your action with a new ViewModel Object.

I would *recommend* a create new ViewModel like so `RequestProcessingDeadLineViewModel`

```
public class RequestProcessingDeadLineViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Fill this in your business layer    
    public List<DateTime> DeadLine { get ; set; }
}
```

Or in the action

```
public ActionResult EditRequestProcessing(RequestProcessing rProcessing)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // ... do your stuff blah blah

            // get related data

            var relatedProcessingData = db.RequestProcessing.Include(p=>p.RequestType);

            // new deadline VM
            var deadLineVM = new RequestProcessingDeadLineViewModel();

            // copy your data to your ViewModel
            foreach(...)
            deadLineVM.DeadLine =  deadLineVM.Date + + deadLineVM.TimeComplete;
            //...
        }

        ...
    }
```